# What is the API end point to get click count of CM360 ads?

Tags: google-analytics-api

My google analytics and google CM360 is integrated and I want to get click count of each ads. Is there any google CM360 API or google analytics API to get CM360 click count of ad?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can create report in CM360 and extract the report data using [CM360 API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/reports/get)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem you need to run a report:
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.3/reports/run

The code can be found here: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/guides/create_reports